# How to make a variable available across multiple ansible playbooks?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

In my first playbook, I am asking user for a value and storing in a variable. I would like that variable to be accessible in other playbooks. There is only one host in the inventory btw.

My first playbook:

```
---
- name: Get the name of the city from the user
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  vars_prompt:
    - name: my_city
      prompt: "Enter the name of city: "
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: Set fact for city
      set_fact:
        city: "{{ my_city }}"
        cacheable: yes
```

In another playbook, when I try to print the variable I set in the previous one, I get an error:

```
---
- name: Print a fact
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Print ansible_facts['city'] variable
      debug:
        msg: "Value of city variable is {{ ansible_facts['city'] }}"
```

Error:

```
fatal: [testing]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'city'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/ansible_tasks/print_fact.yml': line 6, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Print ansible_facts['city'] variable\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Comment: Variables set in one role are available to later roles during the same execution flow. You cannot define a variable in a one playbook and use it n another playbook run.

Comment: So first playbook must be a role instead? The issue is that I can't set the variable manually. The user has to input the variable.

Comment: Second playbook must execute after the first in the same `ansible-playbook` run. There are hacks like saving the variable value into a local file and read it at the second ansible-playbook run, but you cannot save the variable into the memory for future runs.

Comment: "you cannot save the variable into the memory for future runs." is untrue; `hostvars` remain across every play in the playbook, so `set_fact:` of a `vars:` would do as expected

Comment: @mdaniel How can I set a variable interactively and make it a `hostvars` then? I don't know before hand what `hostvars` would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"In my first playbook, I am asking the user for a value and storing it in a variable. I would like that variable to be accessible in other playbooks."***

A: There are many options:

1. Cache the variable. Advantage: It's very simple. Declare the variable `cacheable: true` in *set_fact*. Disadvantage: Available to the present hosts only. The cache will eventually expire.
2. Put the variable into the [custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts). Advantage: The facts will not expire. Disadvantage: Available to the present hosts only. More complex compared with 1). A file must be created on all hosts.
3. Put the variable into the *group_vars/all*. Advantage: Available to all hosts. Relatively simple. Disadvantage: It will work with a particular inventory or a particular directory of playbooks only.

Details:

1. **Cache the variable**

Enable the [cache](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins) if you want to use it. For example,

```ini
shell> grep fact_caching ansible.cfg
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache
fact_caching_prefix = ansible_facts_
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

Then the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        city: my_city
        cacheable: true
```

will store the variable *city* in the cache

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_cache/ansible_facts_localhost 
{
    "city": "my_city"
}
```

The next playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: city
```

will read the cache

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb2.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  city: my_city

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

If you want to cache the same variable in multiple hosts, for example

```bash
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
```

it is sufficient to run the module *set_fact* once. The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        city: my_city
        cacheable: true
      run_once: true
```

will store the variable *city* in the cache of all hosts

```bash
shell> grep -r city /tmp/ansible_cache/
/tmp/ansible_cache/ansible_facts_host_3:    "city": "my_city"
/tmp/ansible_cache/ansible_facts_host_1:    "city": "my_city"
/tmp/ansible_cache/ansible_facts_host_2:    "city": "my_city"
```

The next playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb4.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: city
```

will read the cache

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb4.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  city: my_city
ok: [host_2] => 
  city: my_city
ok: [host_3] => 
  city: my_city

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This is a good way. I also found that creating a custom local fact file in `/etc/ansible.d` on the remote host and reading from it when gathering facts is also a good way to use variable across the playbooks.

Comment: As @Cruise5 mentioned, an alternative is to use a custom facts(local facts) file on the remote host. I didn't know this is supported and found the documentation about it [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts).

Comment: Custom facts mainly serve the purpose of providing facts module [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#ansible-builtin-setup-module-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) doesn't provide by default. For example, a status of custom HW. I updated the answer with more options and comments. There is no silver bullet. Understand the pros and cons and make your choice.